# Alterar valor do csproj através do TeamCity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integração-contínua

Olá, pessoal.

Estou utilizando TeamCity para os aplicações .NET. Configurei alguns projetos, e os build-steps basicamente consistem em buildar a aplicação com o *Visual Studio (.sln) runner* e rodar testes de unidade com *NUnit*, e isso tudo é disparado através do Build Triggers que busca as alterações enviadas para o GitHub.

Estava querendo que durante esse processo de build, o valor da propriedade `MvcBuildViews` fosse alterada para `true`, para poder incluir as telas na compilação.

```xml
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

Encontrei alguns artigos úteis, mas tinham como pré-requisito a utilização do MSBuild. É possível fazer isso de alguma forma mais simples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é criar um Pre-BuildEvent que dispara um programa que vai abrir o arquivo "csproj" e então dar um replace na linha desejada.

Essa aplicação (pode ser feita em C# mesmo, Console Application) pode receber em um dos parâmetros o nome da configuração sendo buildada (i.e. `Debug` ou `Release`) de forma que a substituição só seja feita no modo `Release`.

Exemplo do Pre-BuildEvent:

```
ReplaceConsoleApp.exe "$(ConfigurationName)" "$(SolutionPath)"
```